# qt4: how to export a table to sql script?

Tags: sql, qt4

Can we export schema of a table and it's data from qt code?
Or can we do it with sql script, a query that return a table's schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably manage to export simple tables in a generic manner using only the functions provided by `QSqlDatabase` (via the [`tables()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqldatabase.html#tables) and [`records`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqldatabase.html#record) functions as a starting point), but as far as I know, you'll need to use database-specific queries to get complete schema information.

This is best done, in my opinion, with your specific database implementation's tools. For instance, SQLite has a `.dump` command that does just that. MySQL has a dedicated [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) utility. PostgreSQL has [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html), etc...

It's safer to use pre-built tools for your specific engine. Getting all the DDL statements correct, plugging in the keys and triggers at the right time, worrying about encoding, ... is quite a task.